# How to create RTSP player in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, video-streaming

Is it possible to view video stream (H.264 live feed) over RTP/RTSP in native iPhone ? If not,is it possible to write an application  and then I have rtsp url how to get streaming video in iPhone.

"rtsp://192.168.2.148:1935/live/test.stream"

I got code  Streaming Video in Android using above url, but now I tried iPhone I don't know 
which frameworks are used and how to get Video Streaming please give me any Idea

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue,and I found an excellent ffmpeg player for iOS, [IJKPlayer](https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer).
You can change the build script in config/module.sh to support RTSP.
If you want to play rtsp real time stream.I have already fock another version [IJKPlayer](https://github.com/tbago/ijkplayer) to support that.

Comment: Do you see that after sometimes. Video is delay but soud is good?

Comment: My sollution donnot support sound play.You can use the origin IJKPlayer.

Comment: ah, I mean that video when begin it perfect, but after time, video delay alot with source.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Sure. You can do RTSP stream in iPhone but with the help of some libraries. You can use the **DFURTSPPlayer** for that purpose

https://github.com/durfu/DFURTSPPlayer

Comment: thanks for reply i will try but i said RSTP stream in iPhone but with help of some libraries So please tell me what are libraries to add my project

Comment: DFURTSPPlayer is the library. add it and try

Comment: i am tried getting Video to Server using this url  rtsp://192.168.2.148:1935/live/test.stream
test.stream is video name this but i don't know how to started it so please help me

Comment: @manujmv DFURTSPPlayer when compiled error is coming like "_av_dict_set", referenced from:
      -[RTSPPlayer initWithVideo:usesTcp:] in RTSPPlayer.o
  "_av_free", referenced from:
      -[RTSPPlayer dealloc] in RTSPPlayer.o
  "_av_free_packet", referenced from:
      -[AudioStreamer enqueueBuffer:] in AudioStreamer.o
      -[RTSPPlayer dealloc] in RTSPPlayer.o
  "_av_log", referenced from:
      -[RTSPPlayer initWithVideo:usesTcp:] in RTSPPlayer.o
 what can be other way?